# Control the view in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I created a project with the MVVM model, and done so with the view-first approach.

I have a `TextBox` in my XAML code, along with a `Button` to pass the data from the `TextBox`:

```
<!-- View - XAML code -->
<TextBox
    MinWidth="30"
    Name="TagId"/>

<Button
    Command="{Binding AddTagCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=TagId}"
    Content="Add"/>
```

When I click the button, I want the `TextBox` cleared.
According to the [Prism manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx):

> In some cases, the code-behind may contain UI logic code that implements visual behavior that is difficult or inefficient to express in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML), such as complex animations, or when the code needs to directly manipulate visual elements that are part of the view.

Here's the code behind, and the viewmodel.

```
//View - code behind
public partial class ApplicationStarterView : UserControl
{
    public ApplicationStarterView()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationStarterView(ApplicationStarterViewModel viewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

//View model
public class ApplicationStarterViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public ApplicationStarterViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        AddTagCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(AddTag);
    }

    public ICommand AddTagCommand { get; private set; }

    private void AddTag(object input)
    {
        //Forward stuff
        //Clear TextBox
    }
}
```

Can I in any way squeeze in some code to do a `TagId.Clear()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd bind the text to another property on the view model.

That way, you can skip the command parameter and the `AddTagCommand` can directly read the new `Text` property, do his adding stuff and then clear it, thus updating `TagId`.

Completely unrelated piece of advice: it is almost never a good idea to inject the `IUnityContainer`... if you need to create stuff, use factories.

Comment: Property for ``Text`` sounds like the way to go. What do i do with the UnityContainer then? I need to be able to access it somehow...

Comment: What do you need it for? If you need it to do `Container.Resolve<MyTagType>()`, rather inject an `IMyTagFactory` that has a `CreateTag` method.

Comment: This is the pattern you refer to, correct: http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern. I need the container to get all my different intances in the model. Since I do it view-first, the view creates the view-model, which creates the model, which does stuff for me. I might have misunderstood how the container should be used...

Comment: Yes, that's the pattern I referred to. Don't get me wrong - the container is great for creating instances, that's all what it is made for. BUT - if a class depends on the container, how does a user of that class know what the class uses the container for? If the class depends on a `IXYFactory`, it's obvious that it wants to create `IXY`s. Imagine you have to write a unit test for the class, how would you configure a mock for the container? So better hide the `Container.Resolve` in a factory in production code, and create a mock for the factory in the test.

Comment: Fair point. I will try to do more of that in the future. :) Thanks a lot!